# Unreal Engine 4. Issue with game build after updating to 4.24.2

Tags: unreal-engine4, bug-reporting

My game is not building anymore and give me an error: 
`Cannot open include file: 'Public/Character/BaseCharacter.h': No such file or directory`, but this file exists. Also, I create a new project from scratch and try to add one C++ class and build and face the same issue.

UPD

I found under project properties at VS2019 that in `NMake -> Include Search Path` is not included a path to the game source. Try to add it manually and the problem was resolved but after rebuild faced the same situation.

Comment: I'd try just `#include "Character/BaseCharacter.h"`

Comment: @George already try it but didn't help me. Also try different ways to include header, relative as well as absolute and didn't work.